# Problem with assembly programming and Procedure calls

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, masm

I am using MASM to do some assembly programming. When I try to run my program it crashes immediately when it encounters "call myFunction", even after I've stripped out all the code from the procedure. Here is my code any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    .486
    .model flat
    .stack 100h

    ExitProcess PROTO NEAR32 stdcall, dExitCode:DWORD

    .code
_start:

    call myFunction

    INVOKE ExitProcess,0
    PUBLIC _start

myFunction  proc  near32


myFunction  endp

END
```

Comment: Can you provide more complex example of your code?

Comment: Sorry Eugene but even code this simple crashes on me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change myFunction to

```
myFunction  proc  near32
     ret
myFunction  endp
```

to make it a stub.  In your version, it has no instructions, so it executes whatever follows it in memory.